# Saltstack for firewalld

Tags: saltstack, firewalld, yaml

I am trying to get a state set up so that I can add the associated ports open in firewalld.

Tried every example I can find and all fail.

Here is my current:

```
firewalld:
  service.running:
    - enable: True
  default_zone:
    - public
  services:
    snmpd:
      - short:
        - snmp
      - ports:
        - udp:
          - 161
        - tcp:
          - 161
    ssh:
      - short:
        - ssh
      - ports:
        - tcp:
          - 22
  zones:
    public:
      - short:
        - Public
      - services:
        - ssh
        - snmpd
```

And this leads to an error on the minion of:

State 'firewalld' in SLS 'firewalld.firewalld' is not formed as a list

I've run this through three different YAML validators and all say it's clean so I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the `firewalld-formula` from the [official repository](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/firewalld-formula)?

Please be informed that a "SaltStack Formula" is a "ready-to-use state that you configure using pillars". So, your YAML declaration must *NOT* be a state declaration, but instead a **pillar declaration**.

Let me illustrate:

I'll assume you have your state files in `/srv/salt` and your pillar files in `/srv/pillar`.

To use the `firewalld-formula`, you need to create a "pillar" file. Use the provided `pillar.example` file and save it as `/srv/pillar/firewalld/<target-host>.sls`, and refer to it from `/srv/pillar/top.sls`. For example:

```
# /srv/pillar/top.sls
base:
  # ... other references we skip ...
  'target-host':
    - firewalld.<target-host>
```

*Note: By naming the pillar file `<target-host>.sls`, we can easily make different pillars for different hosts.*

Then, we 'activate' the formula by referencing the `firewalld-formula` from `/srv/salt/top.sls` (or other state files under `/srv/salt/` using the `include:` directive).

I'll assume that you cloned the `firewalld-formula` repo in this way:

```
cd /srv/salt
git clone https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/firewalld-formula.git
ln -s firewalld-formula/firewalld firewalld
```

*Note: The symlink allows us to refer to the state as `firewalld` instead of `firewalld-formula.firewalld`.*

Now, edit the `/srv/salt/top.sls` file to invoke the `firewalld` state:

```
# /srv/salt/top.sls
base:
  # ... other references ...
  'target-host':
    - firewalld
```

Aaand, you're done.

Alternatively, you may use a common state instead and let the Jinja renderer and the Pillar system take care of the 'targeting' details. Let's say your `top.sls` file has the following:

```
# /srv/salt/top.sls
base:
  '*':
    # ...other states...
    - hardening
    # ...more states...
```

Edit the `hardening` state file as such:

```
# /srv/salt/hardening/init.sls

# ...various states we skip

include:
  # ... possible other includes ...
{% if pillar.get('firewalld', false) -%}
  # The following will be included *only* if pillar for the minion has the 'firewalld' key defined
  - firewalld
{% endif -%}
```